# Why is ["something"]["somethingelse"] a valid instruction?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was working on a Node script, and suddenly I got errors when accessing this array:

```
var a = [
    ["foo", "bar"],
    ["ham", "eggs"]
    ["yin", "yang"]
];
```

Obviously, my error was the missing comma after the second element of the array. But why the script compiles without syntax errors? In Node:

```
> ["ham", "eggs"] ["yin", "yang"];
undefined
```

Comment: 1. You first defined an array `["ham", "eggs"]`, 2. You try to get value from it. 3. `"yin", "yang"` would be eval to `"yang"`, so it should be equal to `var anArray = ["ham", "eggs"]; anArray['Yang'];` And there's no key `'yang'` , so you get `undefined`.

Comment: Really amazed !!! It shows array structure like `[["foo","bar"],undefined]`

Comment: `object['key']` looks for a value inside `object` with `key`. So, it is not really a syntax error. It just looks for `["yin", "yang"]` key inside `["ham", "eggs"]` object and returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you all! Comma operator, sigh